# Spring Boot Logging to Database using Logback (Spring Boot 2.3.7)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-logback, logback-classic

I am trying to create DB logging appender, `ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender` this one to be exact. But from what I read, the DB Appender functionality was dropped from Logback some time ago, with no guarantee when it will be back.

https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1609

Now from what I read, there was a vulnerability in there. But not sure what, because I wasn't able to find any info on it?

Now from what I understand, the newer Spring Boot versions come with Logback `1.2.11`, and `DBAppender` was supported till `1.2.8` i believe.

So my question is:

1. Is it safe to exclude the logback that comes with Spring Boot and use the older Logback without causing a risk?
2. Is switching to log4j the best option? That has had its own issues with security this year!

Comment: Check the [docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) as it states "However, DBAppender for logback-classic is available under the following Maven coordinates: ch.qos.logback.db:logback-classic-db:1.2.11.1". It's also present as last comment in the ticket you linked.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle But when I run with Spring boot defaults I keep getting the error `Could not create an Appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender` so probably spring boot uses something newer!